# Task oriented user interface and Rest application server API

Tags: api, architecture, task

I am designing a system where the user interface will be constructed using a mixture of task oriented UI and CRUD UI. This way we want to be able to have an optimal user experience for different user roles.

The client application uses REST/JSON to communicate with the application server.

For the CRUD part the REST API part is mostly straight foreward. But designing the API for the task oriented actions in our application is a little bit more difficult.

How would one go about designing a REST API that makes a distinction between two different actions on a resource that both actually just update the data?

As an example - The user can change a person's address for the following reasons:

1. The address contains a fault, e.g. the street's name is spelled
   wrong.
2. The person has moved to a different address

Both reasons result in the same end situation; the data has changed. But in the REST API there should somehow be a difference to be able to react differently.

Answer (score 2):

Generally a REST resource will be a noun.  However, it is also legitimate for the resource to be a process or process step.  Thus for the example you've given, I might do this:

- Correcting a typo in an address:

> PUT /resource/customer/123/address

- Customer moved, execute a change-of-address:

> POST /resource/customer/123/changeOfAddress

In the latter case, the HTTP body would presumably contain additional information such as "effective date".  Also, the content-location header returned from the above POST likely would contain the URI to resource that shows the old address, the new address, and when the transition occurred.

Thus the changeOfAddress is nominally a "process" but it is practically a noun unto itself; from a modelling POV, it is a first-class citizen.

Comment: Really great answer !

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have different "update" methods then I would simply include something descriptive in the name (e.g: `/Address/UpdateStreetName`).  You could include a "/Update" method but against the more specific names that might start to look a bit ambiguous.

Also, is the API centered around the data or potential user scenarios?  Personally, I would build my API based on the data - but making sure that it covered all likely scenarios. For example, updating the street name individually might make sense (on the basis that it can be mis-spelt) but does that automatically mean that you'd want to offer update ability on every other field individually?  Maybe, maybe not.

To be sure - a good API will allow users to work effectively and cover all / most scenarios (%80 >) without un-due hassle, but by taking a data-centric approach as a rough guide you'll be less likely to duplicate unnecessarily.  For example, there will be multiple reasons to change an address (not all might be known at design time), moving to a different address is only one - but the overall affect would be the same (as the same data is being changed).

Comment: A large part of the application is based on CRUD operations, so choosing a REST style API that is data-centric seems a natural choice to me. But this also has some disadvantages compared to a RPC style API. As an example: the /Address and /Address/UpdateStreetName both target the same resource but now with different URI's. Isn't this just doing a RPC style call in a different format? The overall affect is the same; the address get's updated. But when the person has moved we might want to send this person a postcard to the new address where we do not want to do that when we just fix a typo.

Comment: Well, to me /Address/Update and /Address/UpdateStreetName are different: one implies the whole address can be edited, the other is more precise (but still limited to Address).  You could take a scenario based approach for the more specific cases, maybe something like: /ChangeOfAddress as a change of address might affect more than just the address; so you could use it as a facade to other calls like /PhoneNumber/Update (but I might be straying from the path here).

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a little utility that allows you to post CQRS commands to RESTful url. CQRS is a good match for task oriented UI. But for a few projects it is understood in management scenarios you may want to manage an entire object (eg. ManagingAddress). Just don't forget that by changing a property from all encompassing management UI you could be inadvertently be missing some logic that is capture by a more granular command - in your case ChangingAddress).

In cases like this it is apparent that you are performing two separate commands (one is just more granular than the other). Whether you represent these as two separate URLs is up to you, with the reminder that any addtional objects may require a similar type of CRUD interface and REST URL. But in either case I simply just bake the more granular command into my more complex command (so granular specifics are picked up in your broader all encompassing command).